# Proving that $p\in(0,1)$ & $x\geq1 \Rightarrow p(1+\log(x))\leq x^p$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I have to show that $\forall$ $p \in (0,1)$ and $x \geq 1$ you have $p(1+\log(x)) \leq x^p$. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the function $f(x) = x^p - p\cdot \ln x - p$, with  $x \in [1, \infty)$ and $p \in (0, 1)$.

$$f'(x) = p\cdot x^{p-1} - \dfrac{p}{x} = p\cdot \dfrac{x^p - 1}{x} \geq 0.$$

So $f$ is increasing, and $f(x) \geq f(1) = 1 - p > 0$. So we're done.

Comment: That works! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

$e^x \ge 1+x$.  Therefore $x^p = e^{p\ln(x)} \ge 1 + p \ln(x) \ge p + p \ln(x)$.